# Set Encrypted connection in web.config during wix installation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wix, connection-string

I have got a web application which is using base 64 encrypted connection string.

```
<add name="connString" connectionString="r5IJ/jyd79T65xiCQ5c6m2vj6B9rVjFMfYiOW7WcpDDVZNJcQGDJfaO6kYfNCvlGXYthl+RHhDVMe6TT7R9Gba96EDTPVOkojQH21QX84yRv0qqn+//QDA==" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I am using Wix for packaging the web application. My question is how we can encrypt the connection string with wix installation in web.config for my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple after validating the connection string use the custom action of immediate type to encrypt connection string and then store it to some property.

May a custom action project in visual studio.
and put your encryption logic in it. [WIX CustomActions](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/authoring_custom_actions.html)
Suppose you two properties

```
<property Id="CONSTR" value"abc">
<property Id="CONSTR_ECYTP">
```

In Dialog box refer the first property to text box of connection string.

```
<Control Id="CONNECTIONSTRING" Type="Edit" X="40" Y="76" Width="220" Height="18" Property="CONSTR" Text="{200}" />
```

add a next button to this dialog.

```
<Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Next"></control>
```

Now within this control.
Call your custom action of encryption.

```
<Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Next">
    <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="ENCRYPT_CONNSTR" Order="1" >1</Publish>
    <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="[NEXTDIALOG_ID]" Order="2" >2</Publish>       
</Control>
```

In Custom Action Set the other property like.

```
session["CONSTR_ECYTP"]=Encryptfunction(session["CONSTR"])
```

Comment: it would be awesome if you could give me some refernce